# Two exact templates, sidebar showing in one but not the other

Tags: templates, theme-roots

I'm using the [Roots WP Theme](https://github.com/retlehs/roots) and for some reason when copy pasting the page-custom.php to create a home page template. The new homepage template is showing the sidebar but not the original page-custom template even though the two template files are exactly the same at this moment.

Can anyone explain why this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`config.php`](https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/lib/config.php):

```
function roots_display_sidebar() {
  $sidebar_config = new Roots_Sidebar(
    /**
     * Conditional tag checks (http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
     * Any of these conditional tags that return true won't show the sidebar
     */
    array(
      'is_404',
      'is_front_page'
    ),
    /**
     * Page template checks (via is_page_template())
     * Any of these page templates that return true won't show the sidebar
     */
    array(
      'page-custom.php'
    )
  );

  return $sidebar_config->display;
}
```

So if your *home* is not the front page the sidebar will be displayed. There is probably a way to adjust these settings per filter, but you can also just change the first array to …

```
    array(
      'is_404',
      'is_front_page',
      'is_home'
    ),
```

… to hide the sidebar.

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you so much. How can I buy you a beer via the Internet?

Comment: Good to see you got it solved. Make us happy by giving something back _here_ with answers for other peoples questions.